# How do i update an access database witin c#?

Tags: c#, database

I have a withdrawal screen in my code that i when i withdraw money i want it to update the access database but my code only removes the amount of money off the database from within the program. Once the program is closed the database resets to its previous state.

My code for this screen

```
int moneyselected = 0;
Decimal balance = frmaccount.Balance;

public FrmTransaction()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (moneyselected == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select Amount");
    }
    else
    {
        if (moneyselected > balance)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not enough funds");
        }
        else
        {
            balance = balance - moneyselected;
            OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(FrmLogin.da);

            FrmLogin.da.Update(FrmLogin.ds1, "tblCustomers");
            MessageBox.Show("Amount Withdrawn = " + moneyselected.ToString() + "\r\nBalance = " + balance.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void btnWithdrawreceipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    Form FrmLogin = new FrmLogin();
    this.Hide();
    FrmLogin.Show();
}

private void FrmTransaction_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void rb10_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    moneyselected = 10;
}

private void rb20_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 20;
}

private void rb30_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 30;
}

private void rb40_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 40;
}

private void rb50_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 50;
}

private void rb60_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 60;
}

private void rb70_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 70;
}

private void rb80_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 80;
}

private void rb90_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 90;
}

private void Cashamountbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void rb100_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 100;
}

private void rb150_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 150;
}

private void rb250_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     moneyselected = 250;
}
        }>>LOGIN PAGE<<
    }

namespace BANK_ATM_PROJECT
{
     public partial class FrmLogin : Form
     {
         public FrmLogin()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

    int failedAttempts = 0;

    public static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    string dbProvider;
    string dbSource;

    public static OleDbDataAdapter da;

    public static DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

    string sql;
    string pin;
    int rownum = 0;
    bool valid = false;

    public static decimal balance = 0;
    private void FrmLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
            dbSource = "Data Source = 'D:\\bank11.accdb'";
            con.ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            sql = " SELECT tblCustomers.* FROM tblCustomers";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            rownum = da.Fill(ds1, "tblCustomers");

            con.Close();

            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
        this.Close();

    }
    private bool validate()
    {
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        con.Open();

        sql = "SELECT tblCustomers.* FROM tblCustomers WHERE ((tblCustomers.AccountNo) = '" + txtAccount.Text + "')";
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        rownum = da.Fill(ds1, "tblCustomers");
        con.Close();


        if (rownum != 1)
        {

            return false;

        }

        else
        {
            pin = ds1.Tables["tblCustomers"].Rows[0][4].ToString();
            if (pin == txtPin.Text)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INVALID PIN");
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        valid = validate();
        if (!valid)
        {
            //Increment the number of failed attempts
            failedAttempts += 1;
            if (failedAttempts == 1)

                MessageBox.Show("You Have 2 Attempts Left");

            if (failedAttempts == 2)
                MessageBox.Show("You Have 1 Attempt Left");

            //If equal to 3
            if (failedAttempts == 3)

                MessageBox.Show("Card Retained");

            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            valid = validate();
            if (valid == true)
            {
                if (txtAccount.Text == "11111111" && txtPin.Text == "9999")
                {
                    Frmmanager Manager = new Frmmanager();
                    this.Close();
                    Manager.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    frmaccount account = new frmaccount();
                    this.Close();
                    account.Show();

                    {
                        txtAccount.Clear();
                        txtPin.Clear();

                        valid = validate();
                        if (valid == true)
                        {
                            if (txtAccount.Text == "11111111" && txtPin.Text == "9999")
                            {
                                Frmmanager Manager = new Frmmanager();
                                this.Close();
                                Manager.Show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                frmaccount Account = new frmaccount();
                                this.Close();
                                account.Show();

                                {
                                    txtAccount.Clear();
                                    txtPin.Clear();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I though the
`ds.update` would have updated it but this only seems to work within the program

Any help or advice would be appreciated

Comment: its set within my login page i will add the code to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problerm is in the following code,Here you cretate a new instance of FrmLogin instead of refering to the current instance:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    Form FrmLogin = new FrmLogin();       
    this.Hide();
    FrmLogin.Show();
}
```

try the following:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    FrmLogin obj = (FrmLogin)Application.OpenForms["FrmLogin"];
    this.Hide();
    obj.Show();
}
```

And generraly when you referring to `FrmLogin` is better to use obj as ref in order to be sure you referenning to current instance. So add this to the start of your code:

```
obj = (FrmLogin)Application.OpenForms["FrmLogin"];
```

And every ref to `FrmLogin` make it via `obj`

Answer (score -1):

are you checking the database in debug folder or in your project solution ?
try checking in debug folder.

Comment: i think the post says it runs well at runtime . and when the database is checked after that no changes seem to bieng comit.

Comment: It will remove the correct number from the balance when running but no change is ever made to the physical database itself.

Comment: I have added my code for my login page which contains my dataset and adapter

Comment: Im checking the microsoft access database as this is the one i want to change information on via c#

Comment: what is there any change ?